# Jest не видит модули, константы подключённые через алиасы(aliases)

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, jest

Проект развёрнут с помощью `vue cli`. В файле с тестами я подключаю модули используя алиасы(aliases). Алиасы прописал в `vue.config.js` и `tsconfig.json`. В проекте везде работают, кроме файлов с тестами. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У **Jest** есть собственный конфигурационный файл - `jest.config.js`. Для того, чтобы **Jest** видел ваши алиасы их необходимо прописать в конфиге в свойство `moduleNameMapper`.

Пример:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
  setupFiles: ['./tests/setup.js'],
  'moduleNameMapper': {
    '^Api(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/api/$1',
    '^Components(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1',
    '^Constants(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/constants/$1',
    '^UserComponents(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/components/auth/user/$1',
    '^Exception(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/exceptions/$1',
    '^Helpers(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/helpers/$1',
    '^Mixins(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/mixins/$1',
    '^Plugins(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/plugins/$1',
    '^Router(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/router/$1',
    '^Rules(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/rules/$1',
    '^Store(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/store/$1',
    '^Types(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/types/$1',
    '^Views(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/views/$1',
  }
};
```

[Ассоцыация](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629925/testing-with-jest-and-webpack-aliases).